# IBM Worklight: Change device orientation

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

When I change the orientation of the device from portrait to landscape. The app is closed automatically. The app I used to test is [IBM Worklight Starter application with jQuery Mobile](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/WorklightStarter_jQueryMobile.zip). I have also created a Worklight project in Eclipse and test in real device, the app is closed as well when the orientation is changed.

Environment: Worklight 5.0.6 Android 4.1.1 Samsung Galaxy S3

Here is log from log cat:

04-09 19:05:32.485: D/DroidGap(4535): onMessage(spinner,stop) 
04-09 19:05:35.320: D/DroidGap(4535): Paused the application! 
04-09 19:05:35.320: D/CordovaWebView(4535): Handle the pause 
04-09 19:05:35.330: D/DroidGap(4535): onDestroy() 
04-09 19:05:35.330: D/CordovaWebView(4535): >>> loadUrl(javascript:try{cordova.require('cordova/channel').onDestroy.fire();}catch(e){console.log('exception firing destroy event from native');};)

Are there some problems here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using a `minSdkValue` (in AndroidManifest.xml) of value 17 or so? This is a defect we have noticed (did not get yet to investigate it whether the issue is in Worklight or Android). However, you can overcome it by changing the value to "8". For this, make sure that you also install API Level 8 using the Android SDK manager.